# Padding after <details> tag

Tags: html, css, padding

I am trying to add padding after a `<details>` tag because the next `<p>` is basically touching it...

[image]

I tried adding padding-bottom but it just makes the grey  tag larger and doesn't add space...

The CSS I currently have is:

```
// Start Drop Down Details
details {

    padding: .8em;
    background: #353535;
    border-radius: 20px
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {display: none; }

details summary::before { 
    content:"►"; 
    padding: .7em;
}

details[open] summary::before { 
    content:"▼"; 
    padding: .7em;
}
```

If you want to see what it looks like live you can see it here: https://www.seekadventure.net/d/198-myog-backpacking-quilt-outdoorink

Comment: If you want space on the outside, it's margin you want not padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Padding adds space between the content and the border i.e. making the grey tag bigger.

Margin adds space between the border of an element and the border of other elements.

If you want to add space between the two elements you will need to add margin.

```
details {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: .8em;
    background: #353535;
    border-radius: 20px
}
```